# How can I stabilize my hot sauces?

Tags: sauce, hot-sauce, spicy-hot

I have started producing hot sauces, the taste and consistency is great!
They are cooked sauces, I meant I cook the peppers and vegetables into the vinegar and water, then put them into a food processor. They are not fermented. In time the water and the pulp is separating in the bottle. How can I prevent that?

If possible I'd prefer to use organic ingredients, or at least things produced from plants with relatively little processing.

Comment: I heard carob gum is used for that, but I have no info

Comment: If you're selling it on the basis of it being organic and such -- maybe you'd be better off putting something on the label telling people to shake it before using?  (and that it's specifically because you don't use thickeners that it separates on the shelf)

Comment: Cleaning up comments here as well. We aren't really interested in debating about what is and isn't natural; the question is in a form that invites all answers but hopefully prefers ones in the direction that the OP wants, and readers (and the OP) can simply see the answers and decide for themselves what they want to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These products are called thickeners.

Gum Arabic is often used for this as well as karageenan, xanthan gum, sometimes corn starch or potato starch.

You have to experiment with the different thickeners so you get the consistency you want.

Answer (score 0):

well, you just want to emulsify, so I guess a little flour, in the form of a roux, or beurre manie is a good natural option. Cornstarch is another option, less taste, smoother, but slimier. Arrow root, even more neutral. Or the most natural option is to grate a potato really fine, and boil it for the last two minutes or so.

Answer (score 0):

A very "natural" thickener - if your texture can take it - would be breadcrumbs. They are used in eg romesco sauces too...

Comment: But if you want to store the sauce for a while?